# Exists in whole word in Decisions Splits in Journey Builder doesn't work

Tags: journeybuilder, split

I use often the operator "Exists in whole word" in the email studio to filter on a list of attributes. To do that I separate my values with a coma.
I tried within a journey but it doesn't work...

Do you know if it's a known issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a known issue in Email Studio when using dynamic content: [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWoWQAW)

However it was allegedly fixed in a new version (216). Couldn't find anything specific for journeys. Maybe try updating to the new version? Hope this helps